# Make me understand preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been looking all over the internet for some useful information and I think I found too much. I'm trying to understand regular expressions but don't get it.

Lets for instance say `$data="A bunch of text [link=123] another bunch of text."`, and it should get replaced with `"< a href=\"123.html\">123< /a>"`.

I've been trying around a lot with code similar to this:

`$find = "/[link=[([0-9])]/";

$replace = "< a href=\"$1\">$1< /a>";

echo preg_replace ($find, $replace, $data);`

but the output is always the same as the original $data.

I think I have to see something relevent to my problem understand the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra `[]` around the `()`, and add `+` after the `[0-9]` to quantify it. Also, escape the `[]` that make up the tag itself.

```
$find = "/\[link=(\d+)\]/"; // "\d" is equivalent to "[0-9]"
$replace = "<a href=\"$1.html\">$1</a>";
echo preg_replace($find,$replace,$data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be **\[link=([\d]+)\]**

A good source for an quick overview of regular expression can you find here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

When you really interested in the power of regular expression, you should buy this book: [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002893.do)

A good Programm to test your RexEx on a Windows Client is: [RegEx-Trainer](http://www.sql-und-xml.de/freeware-tools/regex-trainer.zip)

Comment: Thank you. Its a bit confusing with all the information you get from different sources by searching regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `+` quantifier and as a result of this your pattern matches if there is a single digit following `link=`.

And there is an extra pair of `[..]` as a result of this the outer `[...]` will be treated as the character class.

You also forgot the escape the closing `]`.

Solution:

```
$find = "/[link=([0-9]+)\]/";
```

Comment: And the `[]` around the tag itself need escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data= "A bunch of text [link=123] another bunch of text.";
$find = '/\[link=([0-9]+?)\]/';
echo preg_replace($find, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $data);
```